# Symbols for kernelbase.dll could not be downloaded - UWP, Release build only, after Windows 10 update

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've just updated my Windows 10 install to the latest anniversary update; this seems to have included:

- VS 2015 Update 3 (KB3022398)
- Update for Microsoft VS 2015 (KB3165756)
- Security update for MS Windows (KB3176495)
- Update for [blank] (KB2504637)

I noticed that a UWP app I had developed (and successfully run previously) which is pinned to my Start menu seemed to drop it's tile graphic, and didn't start when I tried it.

I then went to run it from VS (Release build) and got the following dialogs, the app still seemed to run ok though.

[image]

[image]

I don't get these dialogs when running a Debug build. 
I tried to enable the symbols settings under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols. Enable "Microsoft Symbols Servers" [as per this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3b667663-53e2-47bf-995d-e7015e354e0b/symbols-for-ntdlldll-could-not-be-downloaded-from-the-microsoft-symbol-servers?forum=vsdebug) but it hasn't resolved the issue.
I do have internet connectivity - but haven't yet been able to try an alternative connection so as to rule out any new network rules.
I have not yet tried to build a brand new blank UWP app to see how that behaves.

Any ideas?  How worried should I be?

Comment: Could you please use fiddler to catch the request of symbol server, is there any file under temporary folder?

Comment: Thanks @GraceFeng-MSFT, the issue seems to have gone away.  Not sure what I did to fix it.  I did Clean the solution once or twice, which may have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Under Debbuging->Symbols there is option as shown in the image, it was unchecked for me. If you check, it forces symbols to be cached and error was gone. It looks like for some reason symbol cache wasnt able to loaded or downloaded.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i ran on the same issue today, since this is so rare occurrence, i had to figure it out my self by tweaking settings around, eventually i found how to fix it.

Go to Project properties->Build and uncheck the "compile with .Net Native Chain" option.

Comment: it makes no sense. this is a crucial option. this cant be the the solution to run a uwp application

Comment: I am not saying that it will not work but it is not a solution a remove an important feature for a bug. Without using "compile with .Net Native Chain" , whole application makes no sense.

Comment: debug  option still supports some kind of native debugging, so not much is lost, the native chain is just a detail.