# Cannot Get Call Stack Correctly on Exception

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, exception

I am using Visual C++ 2008 to write an application to Automate Word. I set the debugger so that it will break on CException and COleException. When debugging, sometimes I will break at the following exception:

First-chance exception at 0x7641c54f in  MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: COleException at memory location 0x068cdbe0.

At this time, the breakpoint is in the function _malloc_dbg, and when I review the call stack, I will get the following one:

[image]

It said the “Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll”. But my program is built with Debug configuration. How to get the Call stack on exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using VS 2008, not sure if this helps but check it out: [Symbols for kernelbase.dll could not be downloaded - UWP, Release build only, after Windows 10 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133984/symbols-for-kernelbase-dll-could-not-be-downloaded-uwp-release-build-only-af)

As far as I can tell, you are building your applications with symbols and debugging information, but the core library (in this case KernelBase.dll) which is used are not built with debugging symbols. You need to get hold of, or enable the debugging symbols for KernelBase.dll.

EDIT: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a95bb8f-b263-4b0c-ae9c-35023c210a11/kernelbasepdb-not-included?forum=vsdebug
it seems you need `kernelbase.pdb`